# ReferenceError: window is not defined in godash

Tags: node.js

I am trying to build a board game and want to use godash to create a board state and update it. I have successfully installed godash into my package.json, but when I require it in the back-end, in my server.js (the file in which I run my server),

`var godash = require ('godash');`

and I run `node server.js`, the CLI responds with this error:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Chidi\gt\projects\Chess-vs-Go\node_modules\godash\dist\godash.js:1:194)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Chidi\gt\projects\Chess-vs-Go\game_state\go_state.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
```

I've seen various "window is not defined" questions on this site in my effort to solve this problem, and the general solution seems to be that the code should be used in a browser environment. However, this is godash, an npm package that is to be used in the back-end. I have tried updating node.js and npm to their latest versions, but the problem still persists. I feel like I am making an obvious error that I can't see, because I went to the [github page for godash](https://github.com/duckpunch/godash) and did not find any closed or open issues similar to this one. Does anyone know what the issue is, and how I can resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, upon further research, I found that there are ways to use npm packages in the browser (e.g via [browserify](http://browserify.org/)) This allowed me to use godash in the browser, where it was looking for a window object.